# multiple linear regression prediction for 12 months in R

Tags: r

I dont know how to set the prediction periods for multiple regression in `R`
I try to predict the next 12 monthly values for my variable y.

Here is my code:

mlrdata is a data.frame with 24 obj and 7 variables

```
lmModel <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = mlrdata)

mlrPrediction <- predict.lm(lmModel, level = 0.95, interval = "prediction")

print(mlrPrediction)
```

After the print call I get somehow 24 periods as prediction.
I want to adjust the number of periods by myself, is it somehow possible?
Or do I interpret it wrong?

Comment: You should probably use an arima model instead.

Comment: You need to use the `newdata` param of `predict.lm`

Comment: it's not a good idea to predict values outside of your data range in a linear model. See comment from @Roland

Comment: The thing is I am using arima actually, but I need a second forecast model. So I thought it would be great if you can predict values of like product y in a relationship with 5 other products.
I like to have another model to like compare my predictions. As said before I use auto.arima and ets. Probably you guys have some other great forecast models you can recommend me.